# How to see whether or not a specifed program has a file open with Batch

Tags: batch-file

Recently I have been building a rather small piece of batch coding to be run in the background using someone elses VBS. What I have been trying to get it to do is (on weekdays, between two set times) open an excel file named "Homework.xlxs"(if it wasn't already running). Then I ran into a problem as I realised that the method I am currently using doesn't check for a specified file or whether or not that file is open. This means that I could be simply fiddling around with Excel and have my code not run the way I would want it to.

Here is my current code:

```
@ECHO off
SET "stime=16:00:00.00"
SET "etime=17:00:00.00"
:start
FOR /F %%F IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek^|Findstr [0-6]') DO SET DOW=%%F
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EXCEL.EXE">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
   SET "running=true"
) ELSE (
   SET "running=false"
)
IF %time% GEQ %stime% IF %time% LEQ %etime% IF %running%==false IF %DOW% NEQ 6 IF %DOW% NEQ 0(
   START /MAX C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\Homework\Homework.xlsx
)
TIMEOUT 60 /NOBREAK > NUL
GOTO start
```

Comment: I gave you the code in one of your previous questions which is why I told you about your logic flaw.

Comment: You can use something like `wmic process where "commandline like 'Excel'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline | findstr Homework` to see if Excel was started with `Homework.xlxs` but this won't address using `File > Open` ...

Comment: Would you mind explaining the code that you gave me Squashman? I'm trying to learn about whaat I am doing instead of just ripping the code I had been given off of the internet.